# Как определить максимально заданную длину поля в oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, метаданные

Когда мы создаем таблицу, мы можем указать максимальную длину поля, например:

```
varchar(25)
```

Как узнать эту максимальную длину?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select column_name, data_type, data_length from all_tab_columns 
where table_name='имя таблицы' and column_name='имя столбца';
```

Answer (score 4):

```
select column_name, data_type, data_precision, data_scale, char_length, char_used
from user_tab_columns where table_name = upper('table_name')
;
```

Где:

- `data_precision`, `data_scale` - макс. кол-во цифр до и после десятичной точки для числовых типов, `null` если не определено.
- `char_length`, `char_used` - макс. длина символьных полей и в каких единицах она измеряется, `char` или `byte`.

Answer (score 0):

Если Вам нужно задать переменную той же длины, то можно так:

```
 sText TableName.ColumnName%Type;
```

Comment: Вы не внимательно прочитали вопрос -- не задать, а узнать длину.

Comment: в каком месте я задаю длину? цели определения длины могут быть разные, и, возможно, для какого-то круга задач это решение будет наиболее правильным

Comment: _в каком месте я задаю длину?_ - вот здесь - _задать переменную той же длины_.